# How to add a mouseover event for LineSeries in amCharts 5?

Tags: amcharts5, lineseries

I want to add a mouseover event for a LineSeries in amCharts 5.

My try, but nothing happens:

```
series.strokes.template.interactionsEnabled = true;
series.strokes.template.events.enableType("pointerover");
series.strokes.template.events.on("pointerover", function(ev) {
  console.log("pointerover event", ev.target);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does look like the correct syntax, and I have it working in this CodePen example: [amCharts5 LineSeries with open data fields #DDV](https://codepen.io/DorkForce/pen/YzLbZKQ?editors=0011).  (Note that for some reason I do not receive the dataContext attribute on the event target, as I would expect)

```
  series.strokes.template.events.on("pointerover", function(ev){
    console.log(ev.target);
  });
```